# ASP.Net WebForm RadioButtonList doesn't postback selected correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net

The RadioButtonList is as the follows with no auto postback.  My problem is when I select option 1 (value 1) and click either link button, the variable NotifyMe in the code behind is always true because the selected item is always on the default.  I tried to set the EnableViewState just for this RadioButtonList and leave the reset of the form without ViewState.  It didn't work either.  Thank you for your help.

```html
<div id="preferencePopup" style="display: none" title="Set Preference">
  Select an option than click either of the button below.
  <div>
    <ul id="preferenceOptions">
      <li>
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="PreferenceNotification" runat="server" CssClass="radioButtonNoBorder">
          <asp:ListItem Text="No notification" Value="1" />
          <asp:ListItem Text="Notification" Value="2" selected="true" />
        </asp:RadioButtonList>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-11 col-sm-12 text-center">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnSavePreference" runat="server" OnClick="btnSavePreference_Click" CssClass="btn btn-default">Clear & Save</asp:LinkButton>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="btnAddAndSave" runat="server" OnClick="btnSavePreference_Click" CssClass="btn btn-default">Add & Save</asp:LinkButton>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
protected void btnSavePreference_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  bool NotifyMe = PreferenceNotification.SelectedItem.Value == "2" ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: I asume your app is on webforms. Maybe you are changing the value on the Page_Load event or  similar?

Comment: It works when I tested it. It would make sense then that what @Rumpelstinsk is commenting is correct.

Comment: In the Page_load() I only have code in the If (!PostBack) block to databound controls.  However, I put a breakpoint at the very beginning of the Page_Load(), and Quick Watched the PreferenceNotification.SelectedItem.Value.  It still says 2 even I specifically selected option 1 before clicking the link button.